# List all items from range, and note their unique row id from outside the range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with a sheet in Google Sheets that basically looks like this

| box number | item 1 | item 2 | item 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | banana | grape | lemon |
| 2 | pear | orange |  |  |

There are a variable number of items, stored in many rows.

I'd like to return this, the items listed in one column, with their associated box number. The box numbers are unique ids, not concurrent with row numbers.

| items | box number |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 1 |
| banana | 1 |
| grape | 1 |
| lemon | 1 |
| pear | 2 |
| orange | 2 |

I'm currently returning the first col with TOCOL, but I've been struggling to figure out the second col.

I tried the following, but I didn't pursue this line of thinking too far:

`=BYROW(TOCOL(B1:E5,1), LAMBDA(range,{range,ROW(range)}))`

I stopped because I realized I don't really understand what's going on under the hood and how to work with it. When I get into these more complicated functions, I lose track of what's returning what, and how these functions loop over arrays (or more accurately, whether they're following the other functions using that array, which is what I was trying to do here with BYROW)

Any general guidance for troubleshooting this type of function is also very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
={tocol(B2:Z,1),tocol(map(A2:A,byrow(B2:Z,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ))),lambda(a,b,if(a="",,wraprows(a,b,a)))),1)}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you!! I never thought to use map(), I don't know it very well!